# Can't get an event on google calendar to show up on iphone calendar app on ios7

Tags: calendar, ios, gmail, google-calendar

I tried everything, even deleting my gmail account and recreating. I create a google account in the Mail, Calendar option and select Email and Calendar. Still, there is nothing I can do to see my events in the iphone calendar. Is there anything I can do to make it work or debug this. The event is in my google calendar, but does not go to my iphone. :(

I am using the latest ios 7.

Comment: I'm assuming you've already done this, but for the sake of clarity, have you opened Calendar.app on your iPhone, selected "Calendars" (in the bottom middle of the screen), and then selected "Show All Calendars"?

Comment: Try going to <https://www.google.com/calendar/syncselect> and enable your calendars. I gave more details at <http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/114142/9226>